# Apache error: cannot load mod_access_compat.so

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to run a PHP App and keep getting an error when trying to set up Apache 2.4.
The error is:

> httpd: Syntax error on line 72 of C:/Apache24/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf
>   cannot load modules/mod_access_compat.so into server:
>   The specified module could not be found.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please show us your `httpd.conf` file. You can [edit] it into your question. When editing, you can use the "{}" button above the editing field to put things in `code markdown`.

Comment: hi, make sure your "ServerRoot" is configured properly.

Comment: And that it uses forward slashes, even on Widows E.G `C:/coding_stuph/apache`

Answer (score 10):

The `ServerRoot` variable inside of `httpd.conf` should look like this:

`ServerRoot "C:/your/path/to/apache/install"`

By default this is `ServerRoot "C:/Apache24"`.

Also remember to check your `DocumentRoot` directive to make sure it is pointing at the actual website code.

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. The path can be whatever you want `C:/Apache24` or `C:/my/custom/path` but the `ServerRoot` must be the same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your Apache24 folder is saved into the C: drive.
Your path to the bin folder that contains the httpd.exe should look like this (in windows that is):

C:\Apache24\bin

not:

C:\Apache24\Apache24\bin

This will work once you have navigated to this directory on the command line and typed httpd.exe, after hitting enter if the cursor just moves to the next line and you get no warning then you're goo to go

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all of the above/below, you could also check if you have the related Visual C++ Redistributables necessary to run both Apache and PHP module for Apache. You'll find out which redistributable you need by checking the description of the download you picked up, or by the name on the module. You'll see a VC followed by a number. Chances are that you need VC 15 or 11.
If that's the case, google VC and the version number, plus the architecture, x86 or x64, and you'll find the Microsoft page to download what you need.
That helped me, hope it helps others.

See you!

Answer (score -2):

pleas go to address :

```
cd /APACHE_HOME/modules
```

and make sure that the "mod_access_compat.so" exist

otherwise you should re-install apache and C++ Packages