# Wordpress XAMPP Apache wont start

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

I am a student that just started out I appologice if I make any misstakes posting this, please let me know if I am doing something wrong in my post.

The problem is starting apache in the XAMPP controlpanel. It says attempting to start apache server but it never starts.[Screen of XAMPP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cYJKL.png)

I have uninstalled Skype, I have also uninstalled AVAST since I saw AVAST in the logg files shown below.

This problem have returned every time I reboot my laptop where XAMPP and wordpress installed. When I do a fresh install everything works fine till I reboot.

I will put the loggs for apache here and I hope I get it right and it doesnt become a wall of text, noob at the wheels here so sorry if i mess the post up :)

This is the access logg:

::1 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:17:35 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wordpress/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4232 "http://localhost/wordpress/internets-historia/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:17:36 +0200] "GET /wordpress/wp-content/cache/jch-optimize/css/3b4d09a8edeadd78829ce5122a3160a8.css HTTP/1.1" 200 3485 "http://localhost/wordpress/wordpress/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"

::1 - - [26/Jun/2020:15:22:35 +0200] "-" 408 - "-" "-"
10.0.0.15 - - [27/Jun/2020:03:23:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "avast! Antivirus"
10.0.0.15 - - [27/Jun/2020:03:23:25 +0200] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7576 "-" "avast! Antivirus"
10.0.0.15 - - [27/Jun/2020:03:23:25 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -
10.0.0.15 - - [27/Jun/2020:03:23:25 +0200] "GET /dashboard/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7576
10.0.0.15 - - [27/Jun/2020:03:23:34 +0200] "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1053 "-" "avast! Antivirus"

The error logg does not contain anything related to the issue.
and the php.error logg is not existing.
My guess is that apache has been the problem all along but I dont know how to fix it now that I uninstalled AVAST and apache still wont start.

I have checked netstats and no program is using port 80.

As I said I am new to this so if this post is missing vital information please let me know what I need to include. Also I have searched and tryed all the solutions regarding this I could find on stackoverflow and some other youtube videos etc. I also hade the same issue other posts seems to have, it went away after i uninstalled AVAST:

```
12:17:01 [Apache] Attempting to start Apache app...
12:17:01 [Apache] Status change detected: running
12:17:02 [Apache] Status change detected: stopped
12:17:02 [Apache] Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
12:17:02 [Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
12:17:02 [Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method. 
12:17:02 [Apache] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
12:17:02 [Apache] the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
12:17:02 [Apache] If you need more help, copy and post this
12:17:02 [Apache] entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: check httpd.log in logs directory. Also go to the bin directory and run `httpd.exe -t ` command share output.

Comment: I cant find httpd.log anywhere (searched entire laptop) Running httpd.exe -e in cmd gives me this output: httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 74 of c:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: Cant find the module. Also thank you so much for taking your time, sorry I am so useless :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 74 of c:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_access_compat.so into server: Cant find the module
```

make sure that the "mod_access_compat.so" exist in c:/xampp/apache/modules folder. Also make sure that ServerRoot should be same `c:/xampp/apache`. Refer [Apache error: cannot load mod_access_compat.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41710820/apache-error-cannot-load-mod-access-compat-so) for more information.

Comment: I do have the mod_acces_compat.so where it should be. In httpd.conf on line 39 it says: ServerRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs" Above it on line 37 Define SRVROOT "C:/xampp/htdocs" That is where xampp is installed, directly under c:

Comment: confirm modules folder path on your machine?

Comment: Sorry for beeing a tool, mod_access_compat.so has the path: xampp/apache/modules  Should my serverRoot path be: ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache/modules" ? or C:/xampp/apache" ?

Comment: Then it should be `C:/xampp/apache`. It will pick up conf and conf.d,conf.moudle.d folder from `C:/xampp/apache`

Comment: Wow that worked, thank you so much! <3 I upvoted but have to few posts so it wont show up till I get more posts in. Truly greatfull for your help and time!

Comment: Have a great day Sir, I will make sure to pay it forward when I get an oppertunity to do so :)

Comment: Oh yes, Finaly :)